# Retrieving the closest matching string from database containing strings;

Tags: sql, string, search, approximate

I have a database where there is a column "Fruits" of type TEXT; for example if i have two strings

```
1. Apple %d Mango %d Banana %d Guava %d Peach %d
2. Grapes %d Plum %d Pomegranate %d Apple %d
```

I want to return string 1 first and then string 2. 
If i my Query string is

```
Apple 4 Mango 6 Banana 7 Guava 8 Peach 2
```

I can remove the %d's from the stored strings if required but in the query string the numbers will be present;
Any idea how can i do this?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: MS SQL or i can use MySQL too.

Comment: You want to look into the full text options that these databases offer.

Comment: Not very clear. If you can try to clarify

Comment: Please tell me where is your confusion?

Comment: @user2764478 I am not very clear on what you are asking for either. What is "Apple %d Mango %d Banana %d Guava %d Peach %d", is this all text within one field in the database for a single record?. Please can you also explain what you mean by "If my query string is Apple 4 Mango 6 Banana 7 Guava 8 Peach 2"?

Answer (score 0):

You said you can remove %d's from the string, to remove numbers from query string you can use REPLACE function.

```
@str is the query string.

REPLACE (REPLACE (REPLACE (REPLACE (REPLACE (REPLACE (REPLACE (REPLACE (REPLACE (REPLACE (@str, '0', ''), '1', ''), '2', ''), '3', ''), '4', ''), '5', ''), '6', ''), '7', ''), '8', ''), '9', '')
```

This would replace all the numbers and then you can query further for your logic.